# Cryptic Quote #1: To Infinity and Beyond!

Tags: cryptic-crosswords, outer-space

This kind of puzzle is relatively straightforward - solve the cryptic clues, fill in the grid, and find the concealed quote! Bonus points for anyone who can tell me who said it *without* Googling it.

---

1. The irony is that an American uncle has wrecked cars (7)
   __ __ __ __ __ __ __
   *06 27 42 52 61 20 30*
2. Limit citation to 80% with a resolution (5)
   __ __ __ __ __
   *55 56 02 11 48*
3. Baby has misshapen appendage and skin discoloration (6)
   __ __ __ __ __ __
   *09 17 19 05 10 14*
4. This evening, the baby eats, almost (7)
   __ __ __ __ __ __ __
   *22 34 49 15 26 04 23*
5. The idea is that it's *not* a big, headless cat (6)
   __ __ __ __ __ __
   *07 16 32 24 41 54*
6. Bar in Game of Thrones, initially (5)
   __ __ __ __ __
   *29 25 01 08 33*
7. Dime is tight, he thayth with a lithp (5)
   __ __ __ __ __
   *35 37 13 43 36*
8. Make morning drink less heady by preceding it with tea and candy (6)
   __ __ __ __ __ __
   *50 53 40 39 38 57*
9. Lone dead bodies are in the woods (6)
   __ __ __ __ __ __
   *62 45 58 60 59 12*
10. Cow's cries mark the beginning of the end for woodland creature (5)
    __ __ __ __ __
    *47 18 51 44 21*
11. Inserted information incorrectly in section of form (5)
    __ __ __ __ __
    *46 31 63 28 03*

[image: Grid]

Comment: Great fun!  Looking forward to Cryptic Quote #2!

Comment: Congrats on 10k!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. The irony is that an American uncle has wrecked cars (7)

   > **SARCASM** (**SAM** + scrambled **CARS**)
2. Limit citation to 80% with a resolution (5)

   > **QUOTA** (**QUOT** = 80% of QUOTE + **A** resolution)
3. Baby has misshapen appendage and skin discoloration (6)

   > **INFANT** (**FIN** and **TAN** misshapen)
4. This evening, the baby eats, almost (7)

   > **TONIGHT** (**TOT** encompasses **NIGH**)
5. The idea is that it's *not* a big, headless cat (6)

   > **NOTION** (**NOT** + (LION - head = **ION**))
6. Bar in Game of Thrones, initially (5)

   > **INGOT** (**IN** + **GOT** (initials of Game of Thrones))
7. Dime is tight, he thayth with a lithp (5)

   > **TENTH** (**TENSE** with a lisp)
8. Make morning drink less heady by preceding it with tea and candy (6)

   > **TOFFEE** (**COFFEE** - head + **T**)
9. Lone dead bodies are in the woods (6)

   > **CORPSE** (**R** (are) in **COPSE**)
10. Cow's cries mark the beginning of the end for woodland creature (5)

    > **MOOSE** (**MOOS** + **E** (beginning of "end"))
11. Inserted information incorrectly in section of form (5)

    > **FIELD** (**FILED** scrambled)

The solution is

> [image]

said by (I did have to google it)

> Pope Pius XII